# Routing deletes "/Index" from URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, indexing, routes

in my application I have a CompanyGroupDataController.cs.
When the execution gets into its main action (Index), through this URL:.../CompanyGroupData/Index, the URL not longer ends in "/Index", so it erases the last part (althoug in the browser bar it keeps it). I think the problem is in my RouteConfig.cs which is this:

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                company = Skill4IT.WebApps.Admin.Helpers.Tools.AdminUrlAccessCode,
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Skill4IT.WebApps.Admin.Controllers" }
          );

           routes.MapRoute(
           name: "spa",
           url: "#{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new
           {
               company = "admin",
               controller = "Home",
               action = "Index",
               id = UrlParameter.Optional
           },
           namespaces: new string[] { "Skill4IT.WebApps.Admin.Controllers" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Catchall",
            url: "{*catchall}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Error",
                action = "Error404",
            }
        );
```

Thanks

Comment: `Index` is one of the default actions provided in the route configuration. This is why it works when you call `/CompanyGroupData`. think of it like this `/CompanyGroupData/{action = "Index"}`.

Comment: So, why does this: HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString(); returns the url without the "/Index" in the end?

Comment: Remove your `action = "Index",` from the defaults if you want it to be included